# Link Provision to Text of pdf

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have searched .pdf using 'exec' method.
Every string returned from 'exec' is stored in a variable.
I need to provide link to every string returned from 'exec' method.
Will anybody guide me in this regard...

Comment: More context please… what "exec" method? External or using Acrobat JavaScript? What kind of script? Which event?

Comment: its acrobat javascript code. Here I have used 
var stri2 = /regex/.exec();
I am searching .pdf file with regular expression.
The regex results are stored in one variable as shown above.
All strings present in above variable need to be provided link to pdf file.

Comment: If you are looping through the words on the page (that's what you do when using Acrobat JavaScript), you can retrieve its coordinates, and then use them for either creating a highlight annotation, or use it as input for zoom. For syntax and further explanations, see Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

Comment: Will you please mention where I need to search "Acrobat JavaScript documentation"? Please tell me whether I need to refer any book for that...

Comment: This page has all the links you need … and even more: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/documentation.html